# How does ASP.Net ensure the correct binding order of internally-bound controls?

Tags: data-binding, servercontrols

If I have something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater DataSource='<%# new List<string>() { 'Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry' } %>' Visible='<%# DataTime.Now.Days == 1 %>' runat="server">
```

How does .Net determine the order of binding? In that example, it needs to bind twice -- it has to bind the List and the boolean from the expression to a Repeater...which it then binds again to loop through it?

In a general sense, I just don't understand how ASP.Net determines the correct binding order.  And when do these binds actually occur in the page lifecycle?